# Difference in storing Unicode strings on OSX (XCode) and Windows (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, xcode, unicode, utf-8, visual-studio-2017

I've a rather complicated problem, but try to break it down to some basic stuff I can't get my head around.

At the end, I need to get a hash out of a user input string, which must be the same on Mac and Windows. After failing with all kinds of approaches, I started with just hashing (`picosha2.h`) a simple `char`. While the ASCII range hashes equal on both platforms e.g. `const char* cc = "ø";` gives different results. Guessing from the error when changing the declaration to `unsigned` is that Xcode treats the `"ø"` as `const char[3]` and Visual Studio treats it as `const char[2]`.

Another example `"書"`, which spits out a correct Unicode char array size of 4 in Xcode, still has only 2 in Visual Studio.

If I look at the actual memory content, I see that Xcode stores `c3 b8` for `"ø"`, which matches the UTF-8 code, while Visual Studio shows `f8`, which would be the value for the Unicode code point for that letter, which confuses me even more (https://www.utf8-chartable.de).

Is there any chance to make Visual Studio interpret (at runtime) strings as UTF-8 and store them the same way as Xcode does?

Comment: How a string literal is stored depends on the encoding the editor uses for the file. So you need to check what settings VS code has for the default encoding of the files.

Comment: `cc = "ø";` would be affected not by the users input locale/charset as much as how your IDE is configured to save source files. If the IDE is configured to save as ASCII you'll get a different result than if it's configured to save files as Latin1 or UTF-8, for example. So, make sure your IDEs/Editors are configured to all save source files the same way (I'd recommend UTF-8) and also investigate compiler flags that tell the compiler how to interpret source files (yes, such options/flags exist).

Comment: @JesperJuhl do the compiler flags really matter for the string literals?

Comment: @t.niese Yes. It matters how the compiler interprets the source file. See, for example; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks everybody for giving some hints. At the end it turned out that the framework i use wasn't prepared to receive unicode strings. Nevertheless the command line option was new to me.

Comment: In C++11 and later, use the [`u8` literal prefix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to ensure the `char` data is UTF-8 encoded, eg: `const char* cc = u8"ø";`

Answer (score 0):

You could set UTF-8 in Visual Studio.

```
Properties->C/C++->Command Line->Additional Options->add /utf-8
```

Also, you could save the file in utf-8 format.

```
Tools->Customize->Commands->Menu bar: File->Add Command->File->Advanced Save Options
```

Then, save files

```
File->Advanced Save Options->select utf-8
```

[image]